# AWS Policy statement: Unknown Error: An unexpected error occurred - Invalid principal in policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

In AWS S3, I have

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement2024",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:053297098999:function:statixxdata"
            },
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::ixxxx2-statixx-data"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

(Some value changed due to security)

[image]

I catch error: Unknown Error: An unexpected error occurred. Invalid principal in policy . How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your policy looks like it is attempting to grant permission for an AWS Lambda function to use the bucket. This is not possible.

Instead, you should:

- Assign an **IAM Role** to the AWS Lambda function
- Change the **Bucket Policy** to grant permissions to the **IAM Role** (not the Lambda function itself)

However, there is an **even better way** to do it:

- Assign an **IAM Role** to the AWS Lambda function
- **Attach an IAM Policy to the IAM Role** and grant it permission to use the bucket ***without using a Bucket Policy***

When assigning permissions to a specific IAM User or IAM Role, it is **preferable to grant the permissions on the IAM entity instead of using a Bucket Policy**. A Bucket Policy is typically only used when granting **public access** or cross-account access.

Also, you probably want to grant the permissions to the bucket like this:

```json
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::ixxxx2-statixx-data",
                "arn:aws:s3:::ixxxx2-statixx-data/*"
            ]
```

This is because some API calls work on the **bucket** while other API calls work on objects **within the bucket**.